# Copy table from one Google Docs file to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Can anyone provide an example script showing how to copy a table from one Google Doc to another? I have tried multiple variations of "Table.insertTable" and "Table.appendTable", but I cannot get it right.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far? [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! I realized that I had to use the "Copy()" function to get a proper handle to the table. So, the final code looks something like this:

```
    var sourcedoc = DocumentApp.openById(sourceid);
    var sourcebody = sourcedoc.getBody();
    var tables = sourcebody.getTables();
    var table = tables[0].copy();
    var destdoc = DocumentApp.openById(destid);
    var destbody = destdoc.getBody();
    var x = destbody.appendTable(table)
```